# OpenLayers SVG animating in Chrome but not FIrefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg, openlayers

I have an SVG that will animate correctly when my site is loaded in Chrome, but only draws to the first step in the animation sequence in Firefox.  It is loaded up in the `ol.style.Icon` format, in a method that seems well tested.

I have pretty much ruled out syntax as an issue, as I can load the SVG directly into Firefox with no problem.

I get the animation to fire consistently using the `map.render` function set through `setInterval`.

The only thing that seems like a clue to me is that the `date:image/svg+xml` shows up in the Network tab of developer tools in Chrome, but is nowhere to be found in the Firefox network profile.

Any thoughts??  This has been stumping me for weeks now.  Sample code is below.  Thanks!

```
 var svgComment = '<svg width="60" height="60" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 60" viewPort="0 0 60 60" class="svgClass">'
    + '<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" stroke="rgb(0, 191, 255)" stroke-width="1" fill="none" opacity="0.8">'
    + '<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="stroke-width" from="1" to="30" dur="0.5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />'
    + '<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0.8" to="0.2" dur="0.5s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" />'
    + '</circle>'
    + '<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)">'
    + '</circle>'
    + '</svg>';

 var commentStyle =  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      src: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgComment)
    })
  });

  var commentVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    name: 'Comments',
    source: commentSource,
    style: commentStyle
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My svg would not animate in Firefox or Chrome using ol.style.Icon .  I tried Overlay with success:

```
var marker = new ol.Overlay({
    //position: ppos,
     positioning: 'center-center',
     element: document.getElementById('geolocate-mark'),
     stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Then, when you know where to put it:

```
marker.setPosition(geolocation.getPosition());
```

where geolocation is the my ol.Geolocation object, which is another topic, but it includes the Coordinate wanted.

and geolocate-mark =

```
<div style="display: none;"><div id="geolocate-mark">
 <img src="/whatever/geolocation-marker.svg"</img></div></div>
```